# Dynamic heading Oracle apex report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have created an apex report using PIVOT function that generate dynamic list of columns `RM & SCR`, When I place the following code in custom heading section:

```
return 'Emp Name:Work Hrs:RM:SCR';
```

It place heading named `RM` & `SCR` correctly but on only first occurance of those columns, however I need same heading subsequently.

How to achieve that?

Comment: So is your main query generating a constant number of columns, or is it dynamic? If the former, then just provide longer delimited list.

Comment: I need dynamic list of columns

Comment: See related thread at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372275/oracle-based-pivot-with-multiple-columns-group